# How can I fix this memory leak with char*?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am writing a short method to get the MAC address on Darwin. However, I keep getting the following error message:

```
malloc: can't allocate region
*** mach_vm_map(size=3907498536060022784) failed (error code=3)
malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I assume that this is due to a memory leak.

I've tried passing the `char* addr` variable by reference, with no success.

My method is:

```
char* getPhysicalAddress() {

    char* addr;
    #ifdef __APPLE__

        FILE *fp = popen("ifconfig en0 | awk '/ether/{print $2}'", "r");

        if (fp != NULL) {
            fscanf(fp, "%s", addr);

            pclose(fp);
        }
        else {
            addr = "[unknown]";
        }

    #endif

    #ifdef __linux__

        FILE* file = popen("cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address", "r");

        if (file != NULL) {
            fscanf(file, "%s", addr);

            pclose(file);
        }
        else {
            addr = "[unknown]";
        }

    #endif

    return addr;
}
```

And in my main function, I call the function with `char* addr = getPhysicalAddress();`.

How can I fix the memory leak I have in this method?

Comment: Could you use `std::string` instead of a raw `char*`?

Comment: There is 0 C++ code in this question . Then, and that is your problem, you are using an uninitialized raw pointer. The pointer points to some random region and you the call fscanf (this is an unsafe function) with the uninitialized raw pointer. Fscanf then reads something to somewhere, corrupting your memory. Very simple solution: Do not use raw pointers. Never, nowhere.

Comment: You should either code in C or change your code to match C++ STL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at this code:

```
char* addr;
...
fscanf(fp, "%s", addr);
```

It looks like, from this code, you want to read from the `fp` file into the string `addr`. However, as written, this code results in Undefined Behavior (oh no!), and it looks like in your case it's corrupting your memory manager, hence the `malloc` error.

So what's going on here? Remember that `addr` isn't really a string. Rather, it's a `char*`, meaning that it's a variable that says "please look over where I'm pointing and you'll find space to store some number of characters." However, you've left it uninitialized, which means that it's pointing at some random region in memory, likely space that you don't actually own. When `fscanf` then tries to write the characters it reads to that location, it's clobbering whatever memory happens to coincidentally be at that spot, which is a Bad Thing.

In other words, this is **not** a memory leak. Rather, it's an uninitialized pointer write.

There are a couple of options for how to fix this. One option would be to convert `addr` from a `char*` to an actual array of characters, which means that `addr` itself would represent "here's some space to put some characters." You'd need to adjust the `fscanf` call to make sure you didn't read too many characters, or you'd risk overflowing the buffer.

Alternatively, since you've tagged this with C++, another option would be to use a type like `std::string` to hold the memory, then using a loop to pull characters from `fp`, appending them to that `std::string` object.

Hope this helps!